# ViewBag.Title value overrides Model.Title for ASP.NET MVC Editor Template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag, mvc-editor-templates, editorformodel

When I set `ViewBag.Title` at the top of a Razor template, the `Model.Title` editor template text box is populated using the value of `ViewBag.Title` instead of the expected `Model.Title` value. Calling `Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Title)` explicitly does not produce this behaviour.

How do I prevent my editor template from showing the `ViewBag.Title` value without maintaining a custom editor template for my model?

### Code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Post " + Model.Title;
}

@Html.EditorFor(x => Model.Title) @* renders "My Title" text box *@
@Html.EditorFor(x => Model)       @* renders "Edit Post My Title" text box *@
```

Answer (score 7):

The value used by `Html.EditorFor` can come from three places: `ModelState`, `ViewData` and `Model`. By the way, `ViewData` and `ViewBag` are the same thing, two ways of interacting with the same underlying dictionary.

So, to avoid conflicts when working with forms, you can either use Model instead, or use a prefix, like `ViewBag._Title`.

---

On this case `ViewBag.Title` is used to share data with the layout, you can also do `Page.Title` without worrying about changing view data.

Comment: Brilliant! Page.Title

Answer (score 3):

Moving the `ViewBag.Title` assignment to the bottom of the page worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to avoid this is just to not use `ViewBag`.

`ViewBag` is a dynamic object and it does take precedence. But you can stuff almost anything in there and it becomes difficult to debug.

Bottom line: If you need to display something dynamic such as a title, put it in your `Model`.

Comment: I use `ViewBag.Title` for the HTML `<title>` meta value displayed in my master layout template. Would `ViewData["Title"]` avoid the problem?

Comment: I ended up just using `ViewBag.PageTitle` instead of `ViewBag.Title` to solve this.